# Is this sum constant for n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, products, infinite-product, q-series

Hi I can prove that this sum is constant in $n\in \mathbb{N}$. However my proof is very long (a few pages with probability involved). Does anyone see a simple proof. The sum in question is (a q-series of sorts) With $|\lambda|<1$, $\lambda$ real

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda^{k^{2}+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{n+k}(1-\lambda^{i})\prod_{i=1}^{k}(1-\lambda^{i})} $$

EDIT:
Some people do not agree the sum is constant in $n$, putting it in matlab for 100 terms in our sum it seems to be constant in $n$? or is my matlab coding that bad ?

Code : run this for different n, and say a=$\lambda$=0.5 when you increase j (i.e how many summands) they converge to the same thing for different n

```
% function for j-summing up products, with parameter n=n, and parameter
% a=lambda
function [S] = sumfunction(n,j,a)

assert(mod(n,1)==0,'n is not a natural nunmber')
assert(n>=0,'n is not a natural nunmber')
assert(mod(j,1)==0,'m is not a natural nunmber')
assert(j>=0,'m is not a natural nunmber')
assert(a<1,'a is not less than 1')


S=0;

for k = 0:j
   x=1-(a).*a.^((0:k+n-1)) ; % creates a vector with elements that we wish to multiply
  y=1-(a).*a.^((0:k-1)) ;  % creates a vector with elements that we wish to multiply

    S=S+(a^(k^(2) + k*n))/(prod(x)*prod(y)) ; 
end
  S;

end
```

Comment: Presumably you mean $|\lambda|<1$.

Comment: Yes sorry, i will change that now

Comment: There I a typo in the formula. In the limit $\lambda \rightarrow 0$ the lowest order term will be $\lambda^{n+1}$, hence the sum will be $n$-dependent.

Comment: The other terms will make up for this the further in the series you go...

Comment: Sorry, it simply does not work like that. The answer given below by MOMO is correct, and demonstrates that the sum for $n=1$ and $n=2$ are different. In a similar fashion it can be shown that the sum in the question will decrease in value for increasing $n$ for small enough values of  $x$. So either there is a typo in the formula or your proof is incorrect. Perhaps you would like to share your approach in proving this result in order to find out which is the case.

Comment: In your code the sum is starting from $k=0$

Comment: My mistake the sum should start from 0 in the question i will re-edit. Very sorry for wasting anyones time

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, for example when $\lambda=0.5$: Denote the summand by $a^n_k>0\ $ for every $n,k\in\mathbb{N}$, then

$$\frac{a^2_k}{a^1_k}=\frac{\lambda ^k}{1-\lambda ^{k+2}}=\frac{1}{\lambda ^{-k}-\lambda ^2}\leq\frac{1}{\lambda ^{-1}-\lambda ^2}<1$$

for every $k\in\mathbb{N}\ $, therefore

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^1_k>\sum_{k=1}^\infty a^2_k$$

Comment: @ MOMO I have no idea why your answer was down voted, because it is correct in demonstrating that the sum in the question is different for $n=1$ and $n=2$. It would be helpful when people that down vote would add some reason for it.

Comment: that's a correct and effective approach (+1)

Answer (score 1):

Given the function 
$$
f_n(x) = \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n} (1-x^i)}
$$
for integer values of $n\geq0$ and real $|x|<1$. Note, that the product $\prod_{i=1}^{0} (1-x^i) = 1$ by definition. Consider the difference 
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_{n+1}(x) - f_n(x) 
& = & \sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{k^2+k(n+1)}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+(n+1)} (1-x^i)}-\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n} (1-x^i)}\\
& = &\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n+1} (1-x^i)}
\left[x^k - (1 - x^{k+n+1}) \right]\\
& = &\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n+1} (1-x^i)}
\left[x^{2 k + n + 1} - (1-x^k)(1 - x^{k+n+1}) \right]\\
& \overset{*}{=} &\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{k^2+kn+2k+n+1}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n+1} (1-x^i)} -\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}(1-x^k)(1 - x^{k+n+1})}{\prod_{i=1}^{k} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n+1} (1-x^i)}\\
& = &\sum_{k \geq 0} \frac{x^{(k+1)^2+(k+1)n}}{\prod_{i=1}^{(k+1)-1} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{(k+1)+n} (1-x^i)} -\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n} (1-x^i)}\\
& = &\sum_{l \geq 1} \frac{x^{l^2+ln}}{\prod_{i=1}^{l-1} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{l+n} (1-x^i)} -\sum_{k \geq 1} \frac{x^{k^2+kn}}{\prod_{i=1}^{k-1} (1-x^i) \prod_{i=1}^{k+n} (1-x^i)}\\& = & 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Note that in step $*$ the term for $k=0$ in the second summation would be zero due to the factor $(1-x^0)$, and hence that the sum starts with $k=1$.

Hence it follows that $f_0(x)=f_1(x)=\dots=f_n(x)$ for all integer values and provided the function converges.

Comment: This also holds replacing $n$ with $-n$

Comment: @Monty, no it does not. For negative values of $n$ the product $\prod_{I=1}^{k+n}$ is in general no longer properly defined when $k+n<0$. Your function in this formulation only makes sense for integers $n \geq 0$. You could however make an extension to negative integers (and even real values of $n$) by expressing the function by means of Pochhammer functions (of which this is a special case). Within that context, the equality can be extended to and would hold for negative integers.